# How can I set the x-axis (or y-axis) value of an asp chart using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts

I have a simple asp chart

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtRISKSCORE" runat="server" Width="450px" BackColor="#1E1E1E" Height="400px">
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title ForeColor="White" Text="Risk Score" Font="Tahoma, 12pt"/>
    </Titles>
        <BorderSkin PageColor="Transparent" BackColor="Transparent" BackHatchStyle="None" />
    <Series>
        <asp:Series Name="Categories" ChartType="Column Palette="EarthTones" ChartArea="MainChartArea" LabelForeColor="White" LabelBackColor="White"></asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea" BackColor="Transparent" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="false">
            <Area3DStyle Enable3D="false"></Area3DStyle>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

What I'd like to do is allow the user to set where a point crosses (i.e. set an x and a y value). I have two sliders that will eventually (with your help) set the x and y value of the point on the chart.

Any Javascript examples would be perfect. I can't seem to find anything on this issue so far.

I've started with this but now I'm stuck. So I add an 'onValueChanged' event to a slider. I've then located the asp chart but how can I set the x(or y)-axis value?

```
function pageLoad(sender, e) {
    var slider = $find("<%=sleNEWSCOREIMPACTSLIDER.ClientID%>");
    slider.add_valueChanged(onValueChanged);
}

function onValueChanged(sender, e) {
    var slider = $find("<%=sleNEWSCOREIMPACTSLIDER.ClientID%>");
    var slidervalue = slider.value;
    var chart = $find("<%=chtRISKSCORE.ClientID%>");
    var series = chart.options.series;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify the chart at client side using the JavaScript. The chart is an image generated at server. So after sliding you need to go back to the server and generate the chart again as per sliding value. If you want a chart that interacts with user input at client side and can be controlled with simple JavaScript  and jquery then you need to use jquery graphs like jqplot etc.